# how to edit procmon.exe's driver filename without breaking procmon.exe file

Tags: hex-editor, procmon, debugger

I have a program that detects that I am running procmon.exe and after searching a lot I found this solution:

> > The Device Name of PM is 'PROCMON10' You can see it if you run the Device Manager from the console (cmd.exe) like this set
> >     devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1 devmgmt.msc Enable in the View option
> >     'show all devices' and then open the non-plug&play node. There you can
> >     see PROCMON10. However you can't do much with it. Deleting it does not
> >     unload it and will not preserve you from rebooting.
>
> As a workaround it just renaming it to 'BROCMON10'. So now
>   Winlicense/Themida will not complain about it anymore. How to Rename
>   PROCMON10 to BROCMON10? Open Procmon.exe in a Hexeditor(I used winhex)
>   and open the String Search&Replace dialog. Search for: "PROCMON" 
>   Replace with: "BROCMON" Options: Care about Case, Search&Replace
>   Unicode String. Save and Done.
>
> Hmm changing the title line of "Process Monitor" to "Brocess
>   Monitor"will completely circumvent the the detection algorithm of
>   Themida and allow to monitor it with PM. However I don't recommand to
>   do this since it might be illegal. Ouch

https://forum.sysinternals.com/process-monitor-themida-tweakvi-clash_topic15130.html

I am trying to rename the driver name from PROCMON23 to BROCMON23.
In the new version of procmon it is PROCMON23 instead of PROCMON10, and after doing a search and replace using a hex editor, the exe file no longer runs and gives me this error:

```
---------------------------
Procmon.exe - Application Error
---------------------------
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Why do you want to rename that file? And what's the problem if any program detects procmon?

Comment: Based on that comment, I suspect we're dealing with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). It would be better to ask about your underlying problem instead of only about your proposed solution.